# How do I get results in my date filter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to create a date filter using the form fields `FROMDATE` and `TODATE`.

This will provide the result as a range from start date to end date.

Here's my model

```
function search($status,$from,$to){
  if( $status =="" || $from =="" || $to =="") {
   $this->db->select('a.*');
   $this->db->from('acc a');
  }

  if( $status !="" || $from !="" || $to !="") {
    $this->db->like('status', $status);
    $this->db->where('fromdate <=',$from);
    $this->db->where('todate >=',$to);
  }

  $result = $this->db->get();
  //echo $this->db->last_query();

  return $result->result();
}
```

My issue is I do not see any results.  Does anyone see what my mistake is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Possible problem #1

If you declare a table's short name, then you have to use it. You declared the `acc` table's short name as `a`.
So you have to use it in the `like` and `where` like this:

```
$this->db->like('a.status', $status);
$this->db->where('a.fromdate <=', $from);
$this->db->where('a.todate >=', $to);
```

## Possible problem #2

Maybe your problem is the DATE's format. I assume that you use `DATE` as the row type in your database. Your `DATE` row probably use the `YYYY-mm-dd` format. If your `$from` or `$to` variable don't use this format, this query will be incorrect.

You can check it by print it to your controller (and then `die();`), or into your log file. You can log anything from anywhere with the command (if you enable it in your `application/config.php`):

```
log_message("error", "this is the text of your log message from date: " . $from . ", and to date: " . $to);
```

Log files are located in `application/logs` folder.

## Tip:

It is better to declare the `if statement` with AND (`&&`) operators, because in this function you have to declare all of the variable.

I hope I could help you solve this problem.